# How to present analytics report of survey & polling conducted via Wagtail Forms

Tags: wagtail

I was trying to use [Wagtail Form Builder](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/index.html) for Survey and Polling purpose.

I want to present the analytics report of all current submissions in charts format right below the survey form on webpage, for example, how much percent of visitors selected option A, B, C, D respectively.

any existing package for that purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the solution myself.  Echarts and HighCharts all support interactive data visualization on webpage.